# ios9 : NSLocalizedString inside framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9.3

I had create a framework that send data to server. Whenever I get response from the server I translate it using NSLocalizedString but it not working.

I tried to change Main Bundle to my Framework Bundle like this :

```
NSString* mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString* frameworkBundlePath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Frameworks/MYFRAMEWORK.framework"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];

[bundle localizedStringForKey:@"Message" value:@"" table:nil];
```

But still not working. is there any way to localized message when the Localizable.string is inside the framework ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I tried to recreate Localizable.string and whenever I want to localize I use this :

```
NSString *message = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] localizedStringForKey:@"MESSAGE" value:nil table:nil];
```

I put this code inside class of framework, so bundle of self.class is direct to framework bundle. Thank's for everybody help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class]`.

Comment: Hi Anton, NSString *message = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] localizedStringForKey:@"Message" value:@"" table:nil]; still not working

Comment: Strange... What is your bundle configuration? Also, this link maybe helpful for your https://github.com/davbeck/TUSafariActivity/blob/master/Pod/Classes/TUSafariActivity.m#L45

Comment: What is self.class here? Make sure it is the class from the framework.

Comment: I tried to NSLog [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class]  when I put in class framework and it show the right path with comment "(loaded)". 

but when I tried log [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Frameworks/MYFRAMEWORK.framework"] , it show different path with comment "(not yet loaded)". 

why bundle with self.class still not working to localizedString ??